# OAuth with 3rd party providers

Tags: oauth

I'm trying to integrate Salesforce with Google apps in Apex. For this I need to do OAuth with google.

However, I'm confused with what value should be given for redirect_uri to google. I can create a vf page for receiving the OAuth callback, but this page needs to be public as the person doing OAuth won't be logged into Salesforce.

How to create a public page in Salesforce that can receive OAuth callback?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using Named Credentials with OAuth, then SF handles all that.

If you really want to do it yourself, create a [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) and make the page visible to the Sites Guest User.

It's difficult to give a redirect_uri as this will be different on sandboxes and production (and it may change for My Domain, or an instance-split). You can do it, but you'll have to keep maintaining a list of all the possible varations